# Are there any python GUI toolkits that play nice with Dark Mode?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, invisible

All I know at the moment is tkinter. When I start one of my GUI applications in dark mode the check boxes and radio buttons aren't any discernibly different whether they are marked or unmarked and text in the entry widgets is invisible. In light mode this is not a problem. "No big deal," I think, "I'll just manually set bg='white' and fg='black' on the applicable widgets." Well, that works for some widgets, but tkinter's filedialogs still suffer from invisible text in dark mode, and I can find no simple way to change their settings. I am on Linux and all three of the desktop environments I have tried them out on (Gnome, KDE Plasma, and MATE) have had the same problem, so I'm betting this isn't a desktop environment issue.

I love dark mode, and I know I'm not the only one. Are there any GUI toolkits available for Python that play nicely with dark mode?

Comment: At that point you may want to create your own file dialog window using `Toplevel`. Then you can use a standard ttk style for all your widgets.

Comment: Relevant [possible-to-have-a-standard-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210391/is-it-possible-to-have-a-standard-style-for-a-widget/52210978#52210978)

Comment: If your only problem is the theming of dialogs in tkinter.filedialog then you can try [tkfilebrowser](https://pypi.org/project/tkfilebrowser/) (for Windows and Linux) which provides filedialogs which supports ttk themes (you can try the black theme from [ttkthemes](https://pypi.org/project/ttkthemes/))