# Change background colour of all labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make my app written in python with a Tkinter GUI to change dependant on whether the device is in light or dark mode. I can't seem to change the colour of each label in tk.

Here is my code so far:

```
def monitor_changes():
    registry = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    key = OpenKey(registry, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize')
    mode = QueryValueEx(key, "AppsUseLightTheme")
    tk.config(bg="#f0f0f0" if mode[0] else "black")
    tk.after(100,monitor_changes)
    for Label in tk:
        if mode[0]:
            Label.config(bg="#f0f0f0")
        else:
            Label.config(bg="black")

monitor_changes()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a standard style for a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210391/is-it-possible-to-have-a-standard-style-for-a-widget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a slight alteration to acw1668's code, I was able to get it to work.
Here is the working code:

```
def monitor_changes():
    registry = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    key = OpenKey(registry, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize')
    mode = QueryValueEx(key, "AppsUseLightTheme")
    tk.config(bg="#f0f0f0" if mode[0] else "black")
    # go through all the children of tk
    for widget in tk.winfo_children():
        # check whether widget is instance of Label
        if isinstance(widget, Label):
            widget.config(background="#f0f0f0" if mode[0] else "black")
            widget.config(foreground="white")
    tk.after(100,monitor_changes)

monitor_changes()
```

Comment: How can I make it transparent?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that `tk` is instance of `Tk()`.  Then you can use `tk.winfo_children()` to get all the children of `tk` and use `isinstance()` to check whether a child is a `Label`:

```
def monitor_changes():
    registry = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    key = OpenKey(registry, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize')
    mode = QueryValueEx(key, "AppsUseLightTheme")
    tk.config(bg="#f0f0f0" if mode[0] else "black")
    # go through all the children of tk
    for widget in tk.winfo_children():
        # check whether widget is instance of Label
        if isinstance(widget, Label):
            widget.config(bg="#f0f0f0" if mode[0] else "black")
    tk.after(100,monitor_changes)
```

Comment: Thanks. I only had to change "bg=" to "background="